# Which man page describes ld linker script syntax?

Tags: ld

I'm pretty sure there is a man page for the `ld` linker script syntax, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GNU ld](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)'s script syntax is documented in its texinfo documentation.

On a GNU/Linux system you can use the following command to reach the relevant documentation:

```
% info ld Scripts
```

Comment: This does not work in "Windows Subsystem for Linux" does it?

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer something more handy than `info`, here is a browsable HTML version of the same: [ld.info: Scripts](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/rtems/doc/html/ld/ld.info.Scripts.html). But it may not be entirely up‑to‑date, as the date is 2004.

Another one is here: [Linker Scripts](http://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.12/ld.info/Scripts.html). There is not date, but a version, which is Binutils 2.12 (not that old).

You may find some others search the web for that exact expression: `"ld.info: Scripts"`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're looking for, but *man ld* works for me.

Also, try http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld

or for a complete manual for LD, get it from binutils or here:

http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/ld.html

(before it was bundled into binutils)

Comment: This is for ld. I'm looking for the linker scripts (that you provide with -T), and those aren't in the ld man page.

Comment: I see.  Man pages usually only have command lines.  Did you look in the LD manual?  http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/ld.html