# where can I find the formal ld linker script syntax?

Tags: grammar, ld, linker-scripts

I am looking for the formal grammar of the linker script. Something similar to the ones given to lex and yacc but not with the other yacc baggage. May be I can find the yacc like grammar if I look directly in the source code of the `ld`. But I don't want to do that now.

I have seen [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245612/which-man-page-describes-ld-linker-script-syntax), but it refers to manpages of `ld`. The manpages are fine to a large extent but they do specify things in somewhat ambiguous manner. For example, 
Take this snippet from the [Assignment: Defining Symbols](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_mono/ld.html#SEC13) It says:

> For example, to create an absolute symbol whose address is the last
>   byte of an output section named .data:

```
 SECTIONS{ ...
   .data :
     {
       *(.data)
       _edata = ABSOLUTE(.) ;
     }
 ... }
```

How is one to interpret the `...`?

This is one example. I may be able to interpret this one thing sufficiently accurately after some struggle; but there are many such examples; so my question is: is there a better and formal specification available for linker scripts? Something like the C grammar that you see in an appendix of the book `The C Language` by Ritchie and Kernighan?

Comment: Voting to close as resource rec. It is unlikely that any source will be more precise than the docs, besides the source code of course... I also encourage you to produce minimal Linux 32-bit asm examples and analyze them with objdump.

Answer (score 1):

Inside GNU LD source, there is [ldgram.y](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=ld/ldgram.y;h=f46aa9ea21096914603c7045290fb0f27aa51ce3;hb=HEAD):

`A YACC grammar to parse a superset of the AT&T linker scripting language. Copyright (C) 1991-2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc. Written by Steve Chamberlain of Cygnus Support (steve@cygnus.com).`

See also [ld/Makefile.am](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=ld/Makefile.am;h=75a481bb4daff4ee479ab9b27d4f0828277c2db5;hb=HEAD#l1967) for the source files that make up LD:

`ld_new_SOURCES = ldgram.y ldlex-wrapper.c lexsup.c ldlang.c \
mri.c ldctor.c ldmain.c \
ldwrite.c ldexp.c ldemul.c ldver.c ldmisc.c ldfile.c ldcref.c $(PLUGIN_C) \
ldbuildid.c`